# Mysql like search with more than one column

Tags: mysql, drupal-7

I have a drupal site with the search option. If user enters the search keyword, i need to compare that with more than one columns and display the records.

I have tried the following query

```
$search = 'test';

$sql_query = db_select('logoinfo', 'l')->fields('l');
$or = db_or();
$or->condition('search_field', '%'.db_like($search).'%','LIKE');
$or->condition('companyname', '%'.db_like($search).'%','LIKE');
$sql_query->condition($or);
$selectlogos =  $sql_query->execute();
```

It displays all the records matching the search keyword with the order of auto increment Id asc.

But i want to display the records first which is having both `search_field` and `companyname` matches with the keyword, after that other records which is matches with either `companyname` or `search_field`. Please advise to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [orderBy](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3aorderBy/7) requires a field name and can't order by an expression, you'll need to use [addExpression](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3aaddExpression/7) to get an alias and then order by that alias. The expression in my example will return 0 if the value is not in both fields and 1 if it is in both fields. As far as I know this should be standard SQL, but it may vary on different database backends; so the expression may need to be adjusted depending on the database you are using.

```
<?php
$search = 'test';
$sql_query = db_select('logoinfo', 'l')->fields('l');
$or = db_or();
$or->condition('search_field', '%'.db_like($search).'%','LIKE');
$or->condition('companyname', '%'.db_like($search).'%','LIKE');
$sql_query->condition($or);

$safe_search = db_like($search);
$ex_alias = $sql_query->addExpression("l.search_field LIKE '%$safe_search%' AND l.companyname LIKE '%$safe_search%'");
$sql_query->orderBy($ex_alias, 'DESC');

$selectlogos =  $sql_query->execute();
?>
```